# do a calculation between oracle sql and java variable inside a java class

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to subtract a date variable from a sql result

Trying to return all records from DB that have same meter entered and register which are variables declared, Variable_date- dates of record < Variable_period

```
String additionalWhereClause = "Utilized='N' AND ("+newMeter+" - MeterReadingDate <"+MeterPeriod+") AND METER_ID =" + meter +" AND METER_REGISTER_ID ="+register+"";
```

`("+newMeter+" - MeterReadingDate <"+MeterPeriod+")` this is the problem when debugging MeterReadingDate from sql shows as a name its not showing as date

Comment: Why are't you using a parameterized query (i.e. [a prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with bind variables instead of embedded values)?

Comment: Have you tried prepared statements in Java Oracle ```String sql = "SELECT STUDENT FROM SCHOOL WHERE SCHOOL LIKE ? ";
PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStmt.setString(1, "DPS");
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();```